# Laravel model record retrieve

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

Now I have a table called `users` and I have a column called `is_active` in the `users` table. If it possible for me to write a code in the model which will only get the `is_active` is `true` when i query `Users::all()` ? And if I would like to get the records with the `is_active` is `false` I can just write `Users::withInActive()->get()` ?

It's just like how the `deleted_at` works in laravel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`global scopes`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#global-scopes) for this. Once you define them, it will be applied for queries automatically. To do this, we can override the `boot` method in the model.

**To fetch only active users:**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class User extends Model{
   ...
   static function boot(){
        parent::boot();
         static::addGlobalScope('active', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('is_active', true); // or 1 if you are using tinyint 
        });
   }

}
```

**To fetch inactive users :**

To fetch in active users, you can just skip the scope attached.

```
User::withoutGlobalScope('active')->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use where() function on your query.

```
Users::where("is_active", true)->get();
```

Like this.

Edit:  Using scope

in your model

```
public function scopeWithInActive($query)
{
    return $query->where('in_active', true);
}
```

and you can use your scope like this

```
$users->withInActive()->get()
```

Comment: I know this. but because its been used in multiple places so i would like to know if its possible to do it on the model level instated of the query like above in the controllers.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I misunderstood your question. You can use scope on your eloquent model. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent. Check Query Scopes section