# When using helper function get_active_countries() can not retrieve the active countries from the database in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am not getting the list of active countries whose status is 1 when using the `get_active_countries()` helper function.
Here is the code:

```
// get all active countries
if (!function_exists('get_active_countries')) {
    function get_active_countries()
    {
        $country_query = Country::query();
    
        $activeCountries = $country_query->isEnabled()->get();
        // dd($activeCountries);

        return $activeCountries;
    }
}
```

Here is the Country model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Country extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the Zone that owns the Country
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function zone()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Zone::class);
    }

    public function scopeIsEnabled($query)
    {
       
        return $query->where('status', 1);
    }

}
```

How to solve it so that we can get the list of active countries from the database?

[UI Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLMGV.png)

Comment: In which place, you are invoking this method "get_active_countries" pls share that code snippet as well.

Comment: Ref : This post might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60943457/laravel-model-record-retrieve